# .htaccess file not being on WAMP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I have WAMP 1.7.4 and I have my .htaccess file in directory www/myProject and I have enabled mod_rewrite in Apache and I have the following code in the           .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^/Search_result/([0-9A-Za-z-]+)$
 localhost/Bookers.com/Search_result.php?search=$1&do=search [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

The file is not being read by the server how can I fix this, please?

Comment: Do you have AllowOverrides set on the directory in question (web root?) in httpd.conf or the included files for the virtual host?

Comment: I have this in my httpd.conf file                                                                             # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

Comment: If you really have a # in front of the line that says AllowOverride all remove it. The # means that the line is a comment. Don't forget to restart Apache after making that change.

Comment: What is `WAMPServer 1.7.4`